# Execute batch-file from browser

Tags: browser, batch-file, firefox-addon, execute

i have got a batch-File. I mostly have to execute it when i'm in my browser (Firefox).
So i dont want to go to the directory and execute it. I want to have something in my browser.

First i thought about making a firefox-add-on. Something like a button, which executes my batch-file. But I failed.
Then i made a bookmark to the file, but it only shows me the content of the batch-file.

Is there any other option to execute a batch-file from the browser?

EDIT: I have found an add-on that creates an button to execute files:

https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/external-application-button/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know a way you can run this from a browser, but perhaps you don't need to. I'd create a global keyboard shortcut. You haven't mentioned your OS so I've assumed Windows.

1. Go to your desktop, right-click and select `New` > `Shortcut`.
2. Browse to your .bat file.
3. Name the shortcut whatever you like - probably best to use `yourfile.bat shortcut` or similar.
4. Right-click your newly-created shortcut and select `Properties`.
5. On the `Shortcut` tab, click into the `Shortcut key` area.
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. I've used <kbd>B</kbd> for bat - you can use what you like, although some shortcuts may be used already in your browser - test and adjust if necessary.
7. Click `OK` - you're good to go!

Comment: Also might be worth looking at AutoHotKey (autohotkey.com), free open source tool can be extremely useful.

Comment: Also, Windows assigns keyboard shortcuts to the first ten items pinned to the taskbar.  `[Win]` (the Windows logo meta key) plus `[1]` through `[0]` will launch the first through tenth item on the taskbar.

Comment: @rojo even better! Thanks, didn't know that!

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. I think i will do it this way